# Using $wpdb to insert data into a table

Tags: database, wpdb

## Intro

---

Hello, I am doing some research on how to to use $wpdb to insert data into a table in my database that is not pre-configured by wordpress...

---

## The Ideal

---

I am working on a walking website, where a user can register, join a team or go solo, and enter their miles on a weekly basis. As they enter their miles, they will be on a leader board, acquire badges, and have their progress displayed on a Google API map of the Appalachian Trail.

I can do all this on a website I build without Wordpress very easily, but this year I thought I would change it up and learn more about how wordpress works...

---

## The Question(s)

---

My major issue, is that I am getting pulled in several directions on what would be best practice? Would it be a page template? A plugin I would need to develop? Or should I use a plugin that allows php in I have pages created? Or some other method I have yet to discover?

---

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, users will update their datas in front-office, and you need to save datas in your custom table.

I think you must check on [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) process which will allow you to post datas in JS to a WP_ajax handler.
This handler will be a PHP function, (can be written in your theme's functions.php) that will insert your datas in your database.